# What is the correct method to auto-crop objects from light background?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to extract objects from scanned images. There could be a few documents on a white background, and I need to crop and rotate them automatically. This seems like a rather simple task, but I've got stuck at some point and get bad results all the time.

I've tried to:

1. Binarise the image and get connected components by performing morphological operations.
2. Perform watershed segmentation by using dilated and eroded binary images as mask components.
3. Apply Canny detector and fill the contours.

None of this gets me good results. If the object does't have contrast edges (i.e a piece of paper on white background), it splits into a lot of separate components. If I connect these components by applying excessive dilation, background noise also expands and everything becomes a mess.

For example, I have an image:

[image]

After applying Canny detector and filling the contours I get something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the components are not connected. They are eve too far from each other to be connected by a reasonable amount of dilation. And when I apply watershed to this mask combined with some background points, it yields very bad results.

Some images are noisy:

[image]

In this particular case I was able to obtain contour of the whole passport by Canny detector because of it's contrast edges. But threshold method doesn't work here.

Comment: Can you include some actual examples of what you are dealing with ?

Comment: I've included an example.

Comment: Should the question's title be rewritten to ".. from very light background ?" or something in that sense ? If you always have a very light background, I can suggest something.

Comment: The background is't always white, but that's the most common case.

Comment: Then you have to better specify the problem, it cannot be solved for any possible kind of background.

Comment: Ok, at least I need to solve it for such king of background, other cases are not that important.

Answer (score 1):

If the images are always on a very light background, then you can binarize with a threshold close to the maximum possible value. After that it is a matter of correcting the binary image to get the objects, but this step will vary depending on how your other images look like.

For instance, the following image at left is what we get with a threshold at 99% of the maximum value after a gaussian filtering on the input. After removing components connected to the border and other small components, and also combining with some basic morphological tools,  we get the image at right.

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you include something that better represents what you have ?

Comment: I've included another example.

Comment: That is a separate problem to be handled, the device you use to acquire these images added that noise I guess. You should be able to estimate the noise and extract it.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a bit wishy-washy but bear with me:

This looks like quite a challenging case for image processing recipes involving only edge detection, morphological operations and segmentation.

What you are not exploiting here is that you (I believe) *know* what your document should look like. You are currently looking at completely general solutions which do not take into account this prior knowledge. If you can get some training data then you can go all the way from simple template/patch-based matching (SSD, Normalized Cross-Correlation) to [more sophisticated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constellation_model) object [detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition) techniques to find the position and rotation of your documents.

My guess is that if your objects are always more or less the same and at the same scale (e.g. passports scanned at a fixed resolution/similar machines) then you can get away with a fairly crude approach. There won't be any one correct method. It's also likely that the technique you end up using will not work until you have done a significant amount of parameter tweaking, so don't give up on anything too quickly.

Comment: I can have any images on input, in fact I need all this only to feed the cropped image to the classifier that operates as a passport detector, so this crop shouldn't be very accurate. I just hoped to have a nice segmentation algorithm as a side effect, but after all the experiments I've found that everything depends heavily on the particular image, and parameter tweaking doesn't help here, because what works for one image doesn't work for another and vice versa.